# nextAll in jquery not work

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

My html is:

```
<div id="div_0" class="clscol">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <label id="imgDelete_0" class="sfDelete">Delete</label>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<div id="div_1" class="clscol">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <label id="imgDelete_1" class="sfDelete">Delete</label>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<div id="div_2" class="clscol">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <label id="imgDelete_2" class="sfDelete">Delete</label>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

and in JQuery I try:

```
  $('.sfDelete').live("click", function() {
    $(this).parents('div:first').nextAll('.clscol').each(function() {
                                alert('hi'); //For test purpose
                                //alert($('.sfColNo').attr('id'));
                            });
 });
```

but I never enter inside a `.nextAll`.Alert never fire.I am using firefox 4.0.Is this browser issue or I am missing somthing.Thanks.

Comment: Please try this lemme know if it works B-) http://jsfiddle.net/C2fuX/2/

Comment: maybe you meant to use `.siblings()` instead of `.nextAll()`. Your current code works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.sfDelete').on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest('div.clscol').nextAll('.clscol').each(function() {
        alert('hi');
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xv6cs/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(this).parents('div.clscol').nextAll('div.clscol')
```